# How many watts does tweeter needs

Tags: amplifier, speakers, ohms-law, watts

I have a speaker with the following specs:

- Max. power -  600W
- Impedance - 4~8 Ohm
- Freq. response - 45Hz-20KHz
- Sensitivity - 98dB/W/M

The tweeter of the right speaker is not working so i want to replace it with new one but i cant decide how many watts should i buy. I read somewhere that the 600Watts of the speaker is the total wattage of the woofer and the tweeter and should be 1:10 ratio.

I am deciding to buy a new tweeter with the following specs:

- Power: 300 Watts
- Impedance: 8 Ohms
- Sensitivity: 104 dB / W / M
- Freq. Response: 2kHz ~ 20kHz

is it okay for the given specifications of the speaker or it'll not be compatible?

Comment: Without a schematic of the filter and what elements is involved, it's impossible to give an answer. The easiest way is to find a new tweeter of the same type or with equal characteristics.

Comment: Buy a good Mylar dome tweeter. Ohms should match previous tweeter. No such thing as a 300 watt tweeter.

Comment: Im sorry if my question is not that clear, I only have basic knowledge of this.

Answer (score 1):

> Sensitivity - 98dB/W/M

OK, so it's a PA or horn speaker, so the tweeter will be compression or piezo.

Maybe the problem isn't the tweeter. Disconnect it and wire it to a headphone jack, which you plug into your PC's line out, and then play some music through it. Tweeters can be destroyed by low frequency, so don't use a power amp for this, the line/headphone output of your PC is fine, as it doesn't have enough power to harm it, you can connect the tweeter directly.

If it works, check the wiring and crossover.

If the tweeter is indeed dead, you'll have to replace it with the same model, unless you want to redo the crossover calculations which depend on the tweeter efficiency and impedance. So look for a manufacturer reference on it.

Unless it's a piezo on a low-cost PA speaker which will sound like junk anyway, in this case you can use something vaguely equivalent.

Without more information (like pics, loudspeaker brand and model, documentation, etc) can't say more.